# Push Notification not working in iOS 12.2?

Tags: push-notification, ios12, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urban Airship push notification service. The notifications are working fine for iOS 12.1.4, but in iOS 12.2 Its not working. Do we need to add any extra code for Support push notification for iOS 12.2 and Above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a server issue from the Urban Airship side and now its resolved.